# Passing a Struct to the redigo Send function breaks it and data is missing

Tags: go, redis

This is my struct, when I get a socket message I readJson and the structs gets filled with the data and all is fine. It goes through some functions, but once it goes through the Send function it serializes it in a weird way that eventually I get back a bunch of numbers and when I convert it to string, data is missing.

```
type Reply struct {
  Topic   string `redis:"topic" json:"topic"`
  Ref string `redis:"ref" json:"ref"`
  Payload struct {
      Status string `redis:"status" json:"status"`
      Response map[string]interface{} `redis:"response" json:"response"`
  } `json:"payload"`
}
```

I just want to broadcast messages in this format.

This is where I get the modified and problematic data

```
func (rr *redisReceiver) run() error {
  l := log.WithField("channel", Channel)
  conn := rr.pool.Get()
  defer conn.Close()
  psc := redis.PubSubConn{Conn: conn}
  psc.Subscribe(Channel)
  go rr.connHandler()
  for {
    switch v := psc.Receive().(type) {
    case redis.Message:
        rr.broadcast(v.Data)
    case redis.Subscription:
        l.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
            "kind":  v.Kind,
            "count": v.Count,
        }).Println("Redis Subscription Received")
        log.Println("Redis Subscription Received")
    case error:
        return errors.New("Error while subscribed to Redis channel")
    default:
        l.WithField("v", v).Info("Unknown Redis receive during subscription")
        log.Println("Unknown Redis receive during subscription")
    }
  }
}
```

Does Redigo not support that type of data structure?

This is the format I get and the format I'm supposed to get.

```
//Get
"{{spr_reply sketchpad map[] 1} {ok map[success:Joined successfully]}}"
//Supposed to get
{event: "spr_reply", topic: "sketchpad", ref: "45", payload: {status: 
"ok", response: {}}}
```

On line 55 is where I get back the "corrupted" data - https://play.golang.org/p/TOzJuvewlP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redigo [supports the following conversions to Redis bulk strings](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#hdr-Executing_Commands):

```
Go Type                 Conversion
[]byte                  Sent as is
string                  Sent as is
int, int64              strconv.FormatInt(v)
float64                 strconv.FormatFloat(v, 'g', -1, 64)
bool                    true -> "1", false -> "0"
nil                     ""
all other types         fmt.Print(v)
```

The `Reply` type is encoding using `fmt.Print(v)`.

It looks like you want to encode the value as JSON. If so, do the encoding in the application.  You can remove the `redis` field tags.

```
writeToRedis(conn redis.Conn, data Reply) error {
    p, err := json.Marshl(data)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "Unable to encode message to json")
    }
    if err := conn.Send("PUBLISH", Channel, p); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "Unable to publish message to Redis")
    }
    if err := conn.Flush(); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "Unable to flush published message to Redis")
    }
    return nil
}
```